# Code compiles fine but vscode still shows the red squiggly lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

So I'm using vscode on windows and I'm compiling my code using g++. The code compiles and runs fine, but vscode is still giving an error for `#include <iostream>`.
[image]

Here's the screenshot of the error.

[image]

And here's a screenshot of it compiling and running fine.
I also ran `g++ --version` and `gdb --version` in cmd and it looks like I installed MinGW correctly.

[image]

Here is c_cpp_properties.json file.

[image]

And here is my task.json file.

Any help would be great! Thanks guys!

Comment: don't post images of text/code, do you assume I type it over to test

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `compilerPath` setting to the path of g++.exe instead of cl.exe and set `intelliSenseMode` to gcc-x64. The language server uses the compiler path to infer the path to the C++ standard library header files. Though since the path to the header files are listed in `includePath`, the language server should have also picked them up.